# How do windowing systems composite final screen?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx

How do compositing window systems like Quartz on MacOS work?

Individual applications can create graphics contexts and associate them with frame buffers on the GPU. I'm assuming the windowing system must also do the same. But how can the windowing system access all the application frame buffers and composite them into it's own?

Is screen tearing in an issue when application when it doesn't "own" the screen? The only point where the "tear" could occur is when the windowing system is reading the application's frame buffer (or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different ways to actually implement this. But the most commonly used method is, that the windowing system itself is responsible for creating window framebuffers and OpenGL contexts. *Applications do not create OpenGL contexts and framebuffers in isolation, if the detination is a window!*

> But how can the windowing system access all the application frame buffers and composite them into it's own?

Well, the windowing system is the actual owner of the window frame buffers in the first place. The applications just have a lease on them.

> Is screen tearing in an issue when application when it doesn't "own" the screen? The only point where the "tear" could occur is when the windowing system is reading the application's frame buffer (or something).

That's what double buffering is for. Buffer swaps are delayed to happen between compositing redraws and applications render to a back buffer, that's not accessed by compositing. Compositing only reads from the front buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Seems like the windowing system would therefore must have tie-ins to the platform's client graphics implementation? I think the "tear" is from swapping front/back buffer while front buffer is being read. But doesn't the compositing process act as a double-buffered setup unto itself? Applications render to a buffer, and that buffer is periodically read into another buffer by the window system.

Comment: @anon: Yes, the window system usually not only has very strong tie-ins to the graphics system. In many cases it *is* the graphics system. What may be confusing is, that the window management (decoration, placement, visibility status) is not necessarily part of the windowing system itself. X11 is a windowing system, as is Win32 GDI or recently Wayland.

Comment: @anon: Regarding double buffering and compositing. Yes, in theory it is possible to use the composition process itself as double buffering method, but there's one important caveat. Compositing is an *all or nothing* operation. Since the per-pixel-opacity values of each and every window must be considered for each redraw, and window contents interact with each other, it's not possible to selectively recompose only select windows (well, if the set of allowed composition operations is limited, it can be somehow done, but it's impractical).

Comment: @anon: (cont.): If all windows are updated at higher than display refresh rate, this poses no problem. However graphically complex applications may take significantly longer to render their window contents than a single display refresh interval. And in that situation a compositor has two choices: Compose a window that's only partially updated, which may either result in tearing, or partially corrupted window contents, *or* delay the whole screen composition which will reduce the whole screen's display update rate to the lowest common denominator. Tearing may be acceptable, but the rest is not!